# How to obtain private key if it is generated but lost for submitting app on iTunes

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, app-store-connect

I have made an iPhone app for the client. Now the Client wants that I should submit his app from his account.

I tried doing that but I am facing a problem.

I downloaded the **Provisioning Certificates** and **Distribution Profile** from my client's account but still I am not able to get the private key.

I asked my client to import the private key from his keychain and give it to me for submission of the app. but there is no private key in his keychain.

It might be a case where in he had previously hired a developer who hasn't given him the private key.

How can I gain that private key?

Or is there a way to re-generate it?

If Yes, How can we re-generate?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks

Comment: you can't. That's the whole point!

Comment: so what is the solution for this? Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly advise you to re-generate the certificates and provisioning profiles for the new app.

Basically, if you have the source code, start from scratch, in iTunes Connect and in Provisioning Portal.

Generate all new certificates and provisioning profiles, and change the bundle id. You will have to change the name, for example from MyApp to MyApp - Does Something, or whatever as iTunes Connect will not allow you to delete app names, or reuse them.

Comment: @WrightCS :Thanks for your input. Actually I am a newbie so can you please tell me what exactly I need to start with? Should I create Provisioning Certificate first or Distribution Profile first?

Comment: I would visit the Provisioning Portal and create the certificates first, the the App ID's, then the Provisioning Profiles. The provisioning portal actually has a virtual assistant that will walk you through what you are supposed to do. Being new, I would read over everything several times until you fully understand it before you proceed with actually creating profiles and certificates. Everything you need to know Apple provides for you in extensive guides available on those sites.